# Using a boolean to access array indices

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, boolean

I have a `boolean` variable, and depending on this variable I want to order an array.

So I have two lists:

```
string[] radiant_players = new string[5];
string[] dire_players = new string[5];
```

and a `boolean` radiant_wins.

I want to make an array which orders these lists depending on whether radiant won or not, so:

```
string[][] games = new string[2][]
games[radiant_wins]=radiant_players;
games[!radiant_wins]=dire_players;
```

Right now I have radiant_wins as an integer taking values 0 and 1, but I want to use this sort of `boolean` structure so that I can access the two possible values.

(also, for some reason the % 2 operator isn't working?)

Comment: `games[radiant_wins ? 0:1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
games[radiant_wins==0 ? 0:1] = radiant_players;
games[radiant_wins==1 ? 0:1] = dire_players;
```

Comment: radiant_wins is what he wants to be a bool

Comment: I know this!!!!  I'm laughing because it's getting voted after the edit is wrong.

Comment: +1 I've changed the answer according to "and a boolean `radiant_wins`." part of the question... Not sure if it is correct but I think it is what OP meant when saying that have to use int.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I only upvoted because your avatar picture scares the hell out of me.  Just sayin'...

Comment: This is the operator I was looking for. I've managed to get it to work now :). I'll give you the + but Yaur should have posted really, his comment got me to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: If `radiant_wins as an integer` then Yaur answer(comment) won't even compile `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`.

Comment: radiant_wins is specified in the question as being a boolean, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that radiant_wins is a `bool`, this will have the desired effect:

```
bool radiant_wins;
games[radiant_wins ? 1 : 0] = radiant_players;
games[radiant_wins ? 0 : 1] = dire_players;
```